# How to delete nested object attribute

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I have a object like this.

```
var Obj = {
    obj1 : {
        val : 1,
        id : 1
    }
    obj2 : {
        val : 2,
        id :2
    }
    obj3 : {
        val : 3,
        id :3
    }
}
```

I want to delete obj1, can anybody suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: This is invalid object!

Comment: @DhavalMarthak If I make `obj=1` then is it valid ?

Comment: @CarlosRivero But in my case it is attributes are dynamic, I can not randomly delete any specific attribute

Comment: Surely you just use the dot notation and set it to undefined? `Obj.obj1 = undefined`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use delete keyword

```
delete Obj.obj1
```

Comment: thanks, or any way by I can retrieve as a loop